# phpspreadsheet not retrieving values for certain cell

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Quite a weird one. I have a spreadsheet that I am trying to read via Phpspreadsheets, but one cell (at least for the moment), is not retrieving any data and I can't figure out why.

The text in B10 (not retrieving) is Mike
The text in B9 (retrieving) is Name

1) I have checked that the formatting on this cell (B10) and cells where data is retrieved is the same
2) I have tried getvalue, getformattedvalue, getcalculated value, all to no avail

Below is my Php code snippet:

```
$A1 = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 9)- 
>getCalculatedValue(); // Returns value
echo $A1;
$A2 = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 10)- 
>getValue(); //returns nothing
echo $A2;
```

There are many other cells with the same problem, but if  can get this one, I'm sure that it's the same for the others...

Where can I start looking? What am I missing (something obvious I'm sure)...

Answer (score 0):

I think that I may have found the answer...
I was loading an xlsm file, and not a plain xls or xlsx file. As soon as I changed to either of these formats, it seemed to behave correctly...